# How to wire Kendo UI Angular Chart to a datasource?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-chart

I have a Kendo UI chart with some series data. When I update the series, the chart data does not change. I see from the documentation that it needs to be wired to a datasource. But the datasource property is not available in Angular tag.

**HTML**

```
<kendo-chart
  [series]="chartConfig.series"
  [valueAxis] ="chartConfig.valueAxes"
  [legend]="chartConfig.legend"
  [title]="chartConfig.title"
  [tooltip]="chartConfig.tooltip"
  (seriesClick)="onSeriesClick($event)"
  (drag)="onDrag($event)"
  (dragStart)="dragStart($event)"
  (dragEnd)="dragEnd($event)">
</kendo-chart>
```

**Typescript**

```
public chartConfig = {
title: {
  text: 'Insight'
},
legend: {
  position: 'bottom'
},

series: [], //Some data 
valueAxes: [], //Some data
categoryAxis: {
  categories: [],

  axisCrossingValues: [24, 24, 0],
  justified: true
},
tooltip: {
  visible: true,
  format: '{0}',
  template: '#= category #/03: #= value #'
}
};
```

When I have an updated value, then I update the series like this.

```
this.chartConfig.series[seriesIndex].data[xAxisIndex] = parseInt(updatedValue.Value);
```

But the Chart doesn't get updated.

Comment: Please show some example code with how your data source is configured at the moment.

Comment: @IraklisGkougkousis Added the code which is currently working. As per documentation I need to be using dataSource to keep chart updated when values change. The dataSource directive does not exist in Kendo Angular package.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. There is no need for `dataSource` directive. What is possibly happening is change detection not picking up the changes. How do you update `chartConfig.series` ?

Comment: I'm updating directly the series value using the indices. I have added additional code in the question.

Comment: OK, try adding this line the `parseInt`: `this.chartConfig.series = [...this.chartConfig.series]`. This will update the reference of `this.chartConfig.series`. I can write a more detailed answer about this if you want.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. The chart loaded with new data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `datasource` directive, you don't need anything like that. The problem is Angular not picking up changes to `this.chartConfig.series`.

Angular change detection checks for reference changes, not simply value changes. The simplest solution for this problem is after whatever updates you perform, change the reference of `this.chartConfig.series` like so:

```js
this.chartConfig.series[seriesIndex].data[xAxisIndex] = parseInt(updatedValue.Value);
this.chartConfig.series = [...this.chartConfig.series];
```

That final line basically creates a new array with the same elements as the original and changes the reference of `this.chartConfig.series` to point to the newly created array. This makes it more likely to be picked up by Angular's change detection.